# Creating a Visual Studio Online team project with Team Foundation Power Tools

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-power-tools

Is it possible to create a new team project with Team Foundation Power Tools?

I have tried using `tfpt.exe` as follows:

`createteamproject /collection:"https://myvsonline.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection" /teamproject:NewProjectName /sourcecontrol:New /processtemplate:"Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 2013.3" /noportal /noreports`

But it fails with:

**The requested operation is not allowed. (type SoapException)SoapException Details: 
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Proxy.CommonStructureService.CreateProject(String projectName, XmlElement structure)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.PCW.CssStructureUploader.Execute(ProjectCreationContext context, XmlNode taskXml)**

I have tried suffixing with credentials:

`/login:myusername,mypassword`

But the same problem occurs.

Is this an authentication issue? Do I need to configure VS Team Services to allow project creation like this?

Comment: This is a really good question.  Creation of team projects works a little bit differently in Visual Studio Online than for Team Foundation Server on-premises.  Going to send the question around to some folks internally...

Comment: Hey, thanks Ed. I also had a look at the API (`Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client`) and discovered you could create project collections and *delete* projects, but not create projects! I don't understand the reasoning for that.. yet :)

Comment: I know what you mean... There's some complexity behind the scenes with team project creation.  The "create team project" API is on the backlog though.

Comment: MrHinsh is correct - you must use the web UI to create projects on VSO at this time.

Answer (score 1):

On Team Services, you can't use the power tools to create team projects.

http://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/reference/reference-vso-project-projects-vsi

Above is a link to the API reference which does not currently support creating team projects.